# How can I search a List(of T) where T is a custom data class?

Tags: vb.net

I think my question is a little more complicated than I can fit in the title. Say I have a data class for contacts:

```
Public Class Contact
    Public Property Name As String
    Public Property Phone As String
    Public Property Fax As String
    Public Property Email As String
End Class
```

I have a `List(Of Contact)` object with several different contacts. How would I search the `List` for the contents of one of the properties and return the resulting `Contact` object?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Linq is probably the simplest way. The matches variable is another List(Of Contact)

```
    Dim list As List(Of Contact) = {New Contact With {.Name = "Andy", .Phone = "1234", .Fax = "", .Email = ""}}

    Dim matches = From c In list
                  Where c.Phone = "1234"
                  Select c
```

Here's a good cheat sheet that I often refer to when trying to remember the basic syntax of things like this.

http://www.harding.edu/fmccown/vbnet_csharp_comparison.html#arrays

Comment: Works great! And the cheat sheet is helpful, too.